# C# EMIT IL performance issue

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, compiler-construction, cil

I'm working on an engine where we copy around lots and lots of properties dynamically at runtime. Depending on the situation, we may or may not modify the property value along the way. It was originally written with reflection, but due to performance issues, we recently re-wrote it in `Reflection.Emit`. The re-write is complete and performance is obviously a lot better, but now the code is being benchmarked against hand-written `C#`. Obviously, to be a fair fight, the hand-written `C#` for the benchmarks has "similar functionality" (you'll see what I mean in a sec) as the `IL`.

Some of the `IL` engine has been signed off on as it has passed with flying colors and is pretty much 1:1 with the hand-written `C#`. This tells me:

1. there is no overhead in calling the dynamic method
2. our general concept and implementation is correct
3. benchmarking is correct
4. `IL` and handwritten `C#` is being tested in exactly the same way, so no funny `JIT` business is going on (I don't think)

We went in expecting the `IL` to be slightly slower then the hand-written, but that has not been the case so far. It's maybe a few ms slower in long rounds, but you can take shortcuts in `IL`, so that helps make up the diff.

In one particular case, its substantially slower. 2x slower.

In `C#`, you'd have:

```
class Source
{
    public string S1 { get; set; }
    public int I1 { get; set; }
    public int I2 { get; set; }
    public double D1 { get; set; }
    public double D2 { get; set; }
    public double D3 { get; set; }
}

class Dest
{
    public string S1 { get; set; }
    public int I1 { get; set; }
    public string I2 { get; set; }
    public double D1 { get; set; }
    public int D2 { get; set; }
    public string D3 { get; set; }
}

static Dest Test(Source s)
{
    Dest d = new Dest();

    object o = s.D3;

    if (o != null)
        d.D3 = o.ToString();

    return d;
}
```

This is what I meant by similar functionality. To be generic, when we copy a property to a string, we first box it and then call `Object.ToString()`. Natively, value types call `ToString` different, thus the code above, to be apples to apples.

If I comment out the `D3` copy/`ToString` and uncomment the other 5 properties, I'm back to 1:1 with the `C#`.

You'll notice that `I2` is `int` -> `string`, but for some reason, that one doesn't have the same problem as with the `double` -> `string`. I get that double `ToString()` is more expensive in general, but that expense should show up in the C# code too, but it doesn't.

The code I emit for the `D3` copy is the same code I emit for the `I2` copy, why the huge overhead on the `D3` copy?

EDIT:

The compiler emits:

```
IL_0000: newobj instance void ConsoleApplication3.Dest::.ctor()
    IL_0005: ldarg.0
    IL_0006: callvirt instance float64 ConsoleApplication3.Source::get_D3()
    IL_000b: box [mscorlib]System.Double
    IL_0010: stloc.0
    IL_0011: dup
    IL_0012: ldloc.0
    IL_0013: brtrue.s IL_0018

    IL_0015: ldnull
    IL_0016: br.s IL_001e

    IL_0018: ldloc.0
    IL_0019: callvirt instance string [mscorlib]System.Object::ToString()

    IL_001e: callvirt instance void ConsoleApplication3.Dest::set_D3(string)
    IL_0023: ret
```

This particular section of my code does not emit the new for the Dest object, that's done elsewhere. The dup is dupeing the Dest object as seen in the `C#` above.

```
LocalBuilder localBuilderObject = generator.DeclareLocal(_typeOfObject);

Label labelNull = generator.DefineLabel();
Label labelNotNull = generator.DefineLabel();

generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, miGetter);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Box, typeSource);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_S, localBuilderObject);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_S, localBuilderObject);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Brtrue, labelNotNull);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Br, labelNull);
generator.MarkLabel(labelNotNull);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_S, localBuilderObject);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, _miToString);
generator.MarkLabel(labelNull);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,miSetter);
```

As I mentioned, I box the type so I can call `Object::ToString()` generically without worrying about value types. Ref types go through this path as well. The `C#` code is made to behave like this and still takes 1/2 the time???

I've been messing with this issue all weekend. Further testing shows other value types are 1:1. `int`, `long`, etc. For some reason the `double` is causing a problem.

Comment: I find your code slightly perplexing: You load the _this_ argument, get the field value, box it, then store that in a local. What do you duplicate, then? Also, please include the actual IL you emit as well as the actual IL that C# generates for its version.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, thanks for the response. I've updated the original post to get rid of the IL wrapper (although it doesn't add any other opcodes or anything). The duplicate is the Dest object. Some diffs in my code: stloc_s/ldloc_s instead of stloc.0/ldloc.0 and branches vs branch shorts. Int/long are 1:1 with C# performance wise, so its just something with double.

Comment: At this level of microbenchmarking, silly things like alignment of the code on pages is enough to trip you up. You'll also have to drill down to the actual code generated by the jitter to see if there's any actual difference; simply continuing to stare at the IL won't help.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, 2x is not exactly micro benchmarking :). Makes a diff between 5 min and 10 min :).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, so after another 5 hrs of messing around with this, I've stumbled across the problem :). FINALLY!! The console app was just slammed together as a test app and had Prefer 32bit UNCHECKED. If I check it, it matches the C# code 1:1, but if I UNCHECK, even the C# takes 2x as long. What's up with that? Why just for double? There doesn't seem to be any difference in the IL between 32bit and 64bit.

Comment: Hmmm.... even just calling someDouble.ToString() in a loop takes 2x as long in 64bit. So I guess that's the issue. Nothing to do with IL.

Comment: "Microbenchmark" refers to the size of the code tested, not to the quantitative performance gains, nor is it a statement on how useful the benchmark is if the operation under test is, in fact, your bottleneck. If I found a bottleneck in `.ToString()`, I'd be rethinking my design. In fact, I'd probably do that before `.ToString()` could become a bottleneck, but that's neither here nor there.

Answer (score 1):

Jump over if `null` (brfalse) instead of double jump. Your benchmark may be false for 3 reasons based on the way (not posted here) you call your generated code :

1. you can call it only with delegate (if you call don't do it in an other generated code)
2. your regular code must be called with a delegate to be comparable.
3. delegate to non static method is faster than delegate build for static method (clr will push null, jump and pop the unused null value before the real treatment). You have to generate a static method with a first unused argument (reference type) and call Delegate.CreateDelegate with target specified explicitly to null for target to prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the `C#` compiled code, fast local-access instructions are used:

```
IL_000b: box [mscorlib]System.Double
IL_0010: stloc.0
IL_0011: dup
IL_0012: ldloc.0
...
IL_0018: ldloc.0
```

Instead, in your `IL` generated code, you use `stloc.s` and `ldloc.s` which also take an operand of the local index.

Also make sure that you cache (you probably are if the `C#` runs only twice faster) the generated method per `Type` it's being generated for.